# Disable Bearer Token validation for a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm trying to skip the token validation for a methods I want to make "public" on my API.

In my StartUp I got the below event to check if a call is authorized:

```
 x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
 {
     OnTokenValidated = async context =>
     {
         var sessionManager = context.HttpContext.GetService<ISessionManager>();

         if (!sessionManager.IsCurrentTokenValid())
         {
             context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
             var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("invalidToken");
             context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
             {
                 await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
             });
         }
     }
 };
```

I've tried to remove `[Authorize]` attribute form the controller but the above code still triggers
Also tried to add `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 1001)]` on the method I want to skip the validation but still the above code triggers.

Do you know how can I disable it only for certain methods ?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you decorate controllers or actions which you want to allow w/o authentication with `[AllowAnonymous]` (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.allowanonymousattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2)).

If you have multiple authentications (Jwt, Cookie) and you want specific endpoints only allowed with a specific authentication, you use the scheme attribute, i.e. `[Authorize(Scheme = "Cookie)]`.

Comment: Cause you are still sending the token I assume. Don't send a token (from the client) on actions which doesn't require authentication

Comment: I cannot control the client unfortunately. They may send it anyway. Is there a way do disable it regardless the client sending the token?

Comment: The code you got above is about token validation (expiry date, audience, issuer, signature), not authentication. So its the wrong place to check. When a client sends a token, the rest service must assume that the user want to access an protected action. When no token is sent, no jwt validation will should be performed and it drops back to the authentication middleware.

Comment: Anyways, not even sure why you check on `OnTokenValidated`, this call back is called after the Jwt token has been validated and the claim principal was created (means: the user has been logged in/authenticated successfully at this point). When its called, you already know the token is valid. What is your goal in performing checks there? Token revokation?

Comment: I check if the token is still valid (expired etc) if it has expired it will return invalid token. There are clients that may call the api every 5 min a method that doesn't requires a token (public). When the token expires those client will get 401 because the token validation will trigger

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-2.2) says: _Invoked **after the security token has passed validation** and a ClaimsIdentity has been generated_. This means that expiry, issuer and audience is **ALREADY** valid when its called, so why checking it a second time?! When ClaimsIdentity is called, it means that all checks been valid and the user is authenticated

Comment: this is where I check if the token store on the DB is the same as in the request + expiring date

Comment: You don't have to do that, a JWT is self-contained. Its protected by its signature. The whole point of JWT is that you **don't** need round trips to the database and by just validating its content and signature is enough to know its valid. What you are doing is opposing to what JWT is meant for

Comment: what if I want to reset the client token to make it invalid ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200900/discussion-between-tseng-and-massimiliano-peluso).

Answer (score 1):

Try to ignore token validation result if the the endpoint implements `AllowAnonymous`

```
x.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
{
    OnTokenValidated = async context =>
    {
        var sessionManager = context.HttpContext.GetService<ISessionManager>();
        var endpoint = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
        var allowAnon = endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<IAllowAnonymous>() != null;

        if (!allowAnon && !sessionManager.IsCurrentTokenValid())
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("invalidToken");
            context.Response.OnStarting(async () =>
            {
                await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(message, 0, message.Length);
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso if it's null that means it doesn't exist **404**, can you verify that you are hitting the correct endpoint? I'd also try to verify that there are no redirects happening.

Comment: there is not IEndpoint fetuare in the list of feature. The endpoint is correct in facts it returns http 200